# Updating widget depending on its visibility in listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, timer, flutter-layout

I want to make this timer, as referred in below image. I am using List View but how can I update widget depending on its visibility in listview, for example 14,16 are out of center so they are half blurred but 15 is in center so its perfectly visible. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Vertical Scrollable Timer]

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Blur

You have to 2 linear gradients for top, bottom blur effect.

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    ListView(...),
    Positioned(top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, height: 24, child: LinearGradient(...),
    Positioned(bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, height: 24, child: LinearGradient(...),
  ]
)
```

### 2.TextStyle in middle

You can refer [numberpicker](https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker) package implement in this [line](https://github.com/MarcinusX/NumberPicker/blob/0287b05bbd5b0127b26f41ff889a0249bb2424fd/lib/src/numberpicker.dart#L206).

In code, the `_intValueFromIndex` function is a key.

In `ListView`, you can implement like the following.

```dart
int _getCurrentSelected(int itemHeight, int containerHeight, double scrollOffset){
  (scrollOffset / itemHeight - containerHeight * 0.5).round();
}
```

I think you need fine tuning for calculation on your demand

Answer (score 0):

try, ListWheelScrollView Widget to achieve this,refer below link.

this widget also gives you options to set opacity of over & below display elements & magnify center element

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html